# bold, italic using UIFontDescriptor

Tags: ios, uitextview

i have an UITextView that have some text and 2 buttons one to make selected texet bold anthor to make it italic

```
    - (IBAction)boldedSelectedText:(UIButton*)sender {
UIFontDescriptor* bodyFontDescriptor=[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor* boldFontdescriptor=[bodyFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
self.body.font=[UIFont  fontWithDescriptor:boldFontdescriptor size:0.0];
 }
  - (IBAction)italicSelectedText:(UIButton *)sender {
UIFontDescriptor* bodyFontDescriptor=[UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor* italicFontdescriptor=[bodyFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
self.body.font=[UIFont  fontWithDescriptor:italicFontdescriptor size:0.0];
}
```

the problem is when i select a text and make it bold then italic , it become italic only and vice
it can not be bold and italic at the same time i don't know why?

Comment: FYI - UITextView has built in support for bold/italic/underlined text through the context menu. You just have to enable a property on the text view to turn it on (I forget its name offhand). No need for extra buttons or font descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the existing symbolic traits first, then add your new trait.
I use a helper method to add/remove my traits,

```
-(void) addOrRemoveFontTraitWithName:(NSString*)traitName andValue:(uint32_t)traitValue
{
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes;
    NSRange selectedRange=[self.attributedTextview selectedRange];
    if (selectedRange.length == 0)
    {
        //no text selected
        attributes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.attributedTextview.typingAttributes];
    }
    else
    {
        attributes=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.attributedTextview.textStorage attributesAtIndex:selectedRange.location effectiveRange:nil]];
    }

    UIFont *currentFont=[attributes objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor=[currentFont fontDescriptor];
    NSString *fontNameAttribute=[[fontDescriptor fontAttributes] objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
    UIFontDescriptor *changedFontDescriptor;
    if ([fontNameAttribute containsString:traitName])
    {
        uint32_t existingTraitsWithNewTrait=[fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] | traitValue;
        changedFontDescriptor=[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithNewTrait];
    }
    else
    {
        uint32_t existingTraitsWithoutTrait=[fontDescriptor symbolicTraits] & ~traitValue;
        changedFontDescriptor=[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:existingTraitsWithoutTrait];
    }
    UIFont *updatedFont=[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:changedFontDescriptor size:0.0];

    [attributes setObject:updatedFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    if (selectedRange.length != 0)
    {
        [self.attributedTextview.textStorage beginEditing];
        [self.attributedTextview.textStorage setAttributes:attributes range:selectedRange];
        [self.attributedTextview.textStorage endEditing];
    }

    [self.attributedTextview setTypingAttributes:attributes];
}
```

If the user has selected some text, the trait is applied to that specific selection, otherwise it is applied to the textview's typingAttributes property.
A bitwise operation is required to add/remove the trait.

This article covers this subject in some detail and is well worth a read
[Using Text Kit to Manage and Draw Text in IOS Apps](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/)

Regards